# Pi3 wireless drivers

Tags: archlinux, pi-3

I am using Archlinux ARM for raspberry pi 3 (Which is identical, for now, to the pi2 image).
I can't get the on board WiFi to work. in lsmod I do see "cfg80211" is loaded, but the interface I see are lo and eth0.

```
iw dev
```

doesn't show up any interface also.
any idea how to make it works?

Comment: I think the drivers included in Raspbian had to be written specially for the Pi's chip, as otherwise they could of used existing ones - you can probably find the source code (at a guess https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.1.y/drivers/net/wireless) and port them to Arch. Which ARM architecture of Arch are you running?

Comment: ALARM is using the same image for pi2 and pi3, so It's actually using ARMv7 architecture. also, I think ALARM is using the same kernel as in the GitHub link.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=9938&p=50835#p50835 :
Currently ALARM is missing some firmware files. I used rpi-update (https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/blob/master/rpi-update) to update my firmware, and now it's working.

Comment: Be carefull when running `rpi-update` manually, as `pacman` handles firmware updates for the pi.

Comment: Don't copy-paste this solution, is no longer valid: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=9938&start=20