# Raspberry Pi 3 On-Board WiFi Antenna on Debian Jessie

Tags: wifi, pi-3, debian

I have Debian Jessie 8.4 running on my Raspberry Pi 3 (download the latest Raspbian image, flash that onto an SD, boot the Pi off it, resize the filesystem with `raspi-config`, put the SD back in my computer, mount the ext partition and delete every file on it but keep the partition table and the boot partition, `debootstrap --arch=armhf jessie`, and make a FSTAB). But I can't get the WiFi to work (the RPi 3-specific on-board WiFi adapter). It doesn't show-up when I run `ifconfig -a`, but I know it's not a non-RPi-specific-distribution-issue because it doesn't show-up when I run `ifconfig -a` on Raspbian and it doesn't appear on the list of adapters in WPA_gui (also on Raspbian). I also do not think it is a hardware issue because I have tried those steps on two different Raspberry Pi 3s purchased months apart, one when the Raspberry Pi 3 came out and one recently. What do I have to do to get the on-board WiFi antenna working as an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43509/pi3-wireless-drivers) closely-related question. Same issue as you, but with ArchLinux.